# Unable to sign in to the website with python selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have written an automation script for a website, when i am passing credentials and clicking on submit, the page gets refreshed with no content in the textbox,  it is not signing in.On doing the same process manually it works.

```
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtUserID"]')
user.send_keys(user_id)

password_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtPassword"]')
password_1.send_keys(password)

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnLogin"]')
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Update the question with your relevant _HTML_ and _error stack trace_

Comment: Please post the URL and HTML code for the same, this info is not complete

Answer (score 0):

By your statement, there could be a possibility that you click the submit button even before the Username and password field is updated with the keys. Try adding delay in between to test if your User id and password are updated and visible in the fields.

Alternatively there could be a chance that you are sending the User id and password to a wrong element.

Comment: Another possible reason is the password after entered by the sendkeys is not the one you give.   Add a long sleep before click submit button, then check the length of the password in text box is same as the length of your given.   In some case, the user input validation attached to the text box will break the sendkeys normal work.

Comment: It doesnt give incoorect password, on clicking the submit button it takes few secs and then reloads the page. I already added delay and checked it still throws the same error

Comment: The send_keys seems to give some problem on a latest Chrome browser. Update your Chrome driver to the latest one. This should solve the problem. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36/

Comment: Yea i did update the chrome driver ... it does pass the credentials and clicks on login... but after that instead of doing inside the website, it reloads the page

Answer (score 0):

for sure there is need to trigger `onChange` event on element, because some elements has hook on that, and if no event triggered, it thinks there is no data inside :)

```
        driver.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))", driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtUserID"]'));
```

or made custom sendkeys() method thenwith this magic inside, to not copypaste :)